# Angularjs ui-router Could not resolve 'results/0' from state 'survey'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to set up my first angular app and I have encountered difficulty with the ui-router. Functionally, the user fills out a survey and is then sent to a page with their individual results of said survey. On submit, the user's results are saved to a factory along with an id that is incremented on each submission. I can't seem to be able to get ui-router to resolve to that individualized page.

Instead, I get this error:

> Could not resolve 'results/0' from state 'survey'

Code from FormCrtl:

```
routerApp.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', 'questions', 'users', 'results',
    function($scope, questions, users, results){
        $scope.responses = [];
        $scope.results = [];
        $scope.multChoice = [];
        $scope.imageQuestions = [];
        $scope.questions = questions.questions;
        $scope.code = results.lastId;
         results.results.push($scope.results);
        results.lastId++;

        console.log($scope.results);
        users.create({responses: $scope.responses, results: $scope.results});
```

Code from ResultsCtrl:

```
routerApp.controller('ResultsCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'results', function($scope, $stateParams, results){
    console.log('hello world');
}]);
```

Code from ui-router:

```
.state('results', {
            url: '/results/{id:int}',
            templateUrl: '../../views/results.html',
            controller: 'ResultsCtrl',
            resolve: {
            post: ['$stateParams', 'results', function($stateParams, results) {
              return results.results[id];
            }]
          }})
```

Code from survey html:

```
    </div>
    <label>Please confirm that you have answered all of the questions</label>
    <button ng-click = 'addUser()' ui-sref = 'results/{{code}}'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Code from results factory:

```
routerApp.factory('results', [ function(){
    var o = {
        results: [],
        lastId: 0
    };

    return o;
}]);
```

Comment: Is nothing happening when you click the button?

Comment: And what is the console printing?

Comment: correct, I get the error in the title

Comment: What do you mean in the title?

Comment: Where is addUser() defined?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean

Comment: addUser() is defined in FormCtrl (which is some 50-60 lines of irrelevant, working code), but it is running as normal. It is the redirect that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong state name inside the `ui-sref` directive and that causes you to get the error. The `ui-sref` directive does accept the `stateName` and search it through the registered states.

```
ui-sref = 'results({id: code})'
```

Comment: That does not error, so it's a step in the right direction, but it does not redirect.

Comment: Yes, it did not error, but it did not redirect either.

Comment: No, not anymore after changing my code as the answer above suggested; however, the code is still not working. Any suggestion as to how to make the rerouting work?